# Warum heißt es Gedächtnis, aber Bedürfnis?

Tags: spelling

Warum schreibt man nicht Bedürf**t**nis, analog zu Gedäch**t**nis, obwohl in beiden Wörtern kein *t* gesprochen wird?

Comment: Ah; so etwas sollte in der Frage stehen. Gut, dann ist die Antwort: Die Wörter werden unterschiedlich geschrieben, weil sie *in der Standardsprache* unterschiedlich ausgesprochen werden, einmal mit _t_ und einmal ohne _t_.

Comment: Gibt es wirklich Dialekte bei euch, die ***'Gedächnis'*** sagen? Das assoziiert ja eher etwas mit *'Dach eines grösseren Gebäudes'* -> Das Gedach/Gedächnis...

Comment: @mramosch Ich bin aus Berlin, aber ich spreche eigentlich soweit hochdeutsch.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Ich meine Du solltest üben, wenn Du kein t in Gedächtnis sprichst. Prinziipiell finde ich, kann man solche Fragen stellen, wenn man im Wortstamm große Ähnlichkeiten findet, aber denken und bedürfen sind nun nicht eben ähnlich.

Comment: @mramosch
"Gibt es wirklich Dialekte bei euch, die 'Gedächnis' sagen? " Ich kann mich ehrlich gesagt nicht erinnern, jemals jemanden gehört zu haben, der das t in Gedächtnis ausgesprochen hat.

Comment: @FUZxxl Soo lange dabei, und du sagst immer noch Hochdeutsch statt Standarddeutsch? ;)

Comment: @Jan Ich nutze diese Seite nicht sonderlich häufig. Ich bin eher auf Stack Overflow und Codegolf aktiv.

Comment: @anion: ***Nur*** mit *'t'* bei uns - es ist zwar relativ weich, aber eindeutig von Gedäch_nis zu unterscheiden... - Aber nicht *'Gedächt-nis'* sondern *'Gedäch-tnis'*!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Die Prämisse ist falsch: das t in Gedächtnis *wird* (zumindest in der Hochsprache und allen mir persönlich bekannten Dialekten) ausgesprochen.

Comment: 100% Zustimmung. Auch in den Österreichischen Dialekten wird das t gesprochen.

Answer (score 3):

Die Wortgruppen um die Endung ***'-nis'*** sind im Deutschen sehr dünn gesät.

Mit ***'-chtnis'*** scheint es nur *'Vermächtnis'* (vermachen) und *'Gedächtnis'* ([ge]denken) zu geben.

Auffallend ist auch, dass ausser diesen zweien nur noch die Zusammensetzungen mit Wörtern aus der Gruppe *'kennen'* einen zusätzlichen Fugenlaut 't' einschieben (z.B. *'Bekenntnis'*). Die restlichen nutzen nur das Buchstabenmaterial aus dem Stammwort.

Zu den ***'-fnis'*** Wörtern gibt es noch zu sagen, dass sie ausser *'Besäufnis'* und *'Treffnis'* fast ausnahmslos aus ***'-ürfnis'*** bestehen, wie *'Bedürfnis'* und *'Zerwürfnis'*.

Comment: Wiesoo ist das "ch" vor "tnis" relevant, wieso "ür" vor "fnis"? Kommt mir sehr willkürlich vor. Weitere Frage: Wie häufig muss eine Endung sein, um nicht dünn gesähtl zu sein?  Wieviele dünn gesäte Endungen gibt es denn, und wieviele andere? Welche Frage beantwortet überhaupt ein Exkurs in Häufigkeiten?

Comment: @userunknown: **'Relevanz:'** Weil die OP genau nach 'Gedä**CH**tnis' und 'Bed**ÜR**fnis' fragt. -  **'Häufigkeit:'** wohl mehr als 2 Worte wie bei *'Gedächtnis/Vermächtnis'* - **'Antwort':** Die 'Antwort' ist, dass eine strenge grammatikalische Regelung für solche *'Kleinstgruppen'* wohl eher nicht zu erwarten ist und sie daher als *'Sonderfälle'* ohne klare Definition hingenommen werden können.

Comment: Außerdem wurde die Frage nachträglich editiert, was die Antwort jetzt off-topic erscheinen lässt. Ursprünglich hieß es nur: ***'Warum schreibt man nicht Bedürftnis, analog zu Gedächtnis?'***

Answer (score 1):

Gedächtnis kommt ja aus dem Griechischen und heißt so viel wie "Erinnerung", denn im Gedächtnis ist ja das "Gedachte".

Das Wort "Bedürfnis" hat (vermute ich) eine ganz andere Herkunft.